# Cannot use validateJsonAgainstSchema in katalon

Tags: java, automation, katalon-studio

I have a response and need to validate its structure to be valid json or not => I searched out the following way and applied in Katalon

```
String jsonPass =
"""
 {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The person's first name."
    }
}
}
"""
ResponseObject response = resp.getResponseBodyContent()
boolean successful = WS.validateJsonAgainstSchema(response,jsonPass)
```

But an error occurred that I cannot use validateJsonAgainstSchema

I imported the following but it didn't work  => Could you tell me what should I do?

```
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ResponseObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.verification.WSResponseManager
import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords as WS
```